# AnimationDrawable animates fast after visibility(gone) followed by visibility(visible)

Tags: android

I have an ImageView that is being used to show some frame animation.
The Duration for these images are all set to 100.

However, the ImageView needs to be hidden sometimes. So the animation is stopped and the ImageView is set to GONE.

When it's time to show the ImageView again, its visibility is set to VISIBLE and the animation is started.

HOWEVER - now the animation is really fast; instead of a duration of 100, it looks like 50. But when I check the duration it still says 100 - but it definitely doesn't look like it.

The code to hide and show the ImageView is as follows:

```
    //hide the animation
    final AnimationDrawable frameAnim = (AnimationDrawable) animImgView.getBackground();
    if (frameAnim.isRunning() == true)
    {
        frameAnim.stop();
    }

    frameAnim.setVisible(false, false);
    animImgView.setVisibility(View.GONE);




    //show animation
    animImgView.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);

    final AnimationDrawable frameAnim = (AnimationDrawable) animImgView.getBackground();
    frameAnim.setVisible(true, true);
    frameAnim.start();
```

What could be the trouble ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

After some experimentation I found that the best way is to simply implement:

```
//hide the animation
animImgView.setVisibility(View.GONE);


//show animation
animImgView.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
```

this will preserve the animation speed. My original intent with the animation stop/start was to ensure the CPU wasn't doing more than was needed.

Answer (score 0):

To achieve the original goal of not just changing visibility, but also stopping the animation when invisible:

```
//hide the animation
animImgView.setVisibility(View.GONE);

//stop animation
final AnimationDrawable frameAnim = (AnimationDrawable) animImgView.getBackground();
if (frameAnim.isRunning() == true)
{
    frameAnim.stop();
}

frameAnim.setVisible(false, false);



//start animation
final AnimationDrawable frameAnim = (AnimationDrawable)  animImgView.getBackground();
frameAnim.setVisible(true, true);
frameAnim.start();

//show animation
animImgView.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
```

The difference here is that starting and stopping the animation occurs while the ImageView is invisible/gone. For some reason, starting and stopping the animation when it is visible causes the timing issues.

Source: I ran into this problem myself and fixed it using this technique.

Answer (score 0):

Struggling with Android I found next solution:

**don't use start() and stop() methods.**

Use setVisible(true, true) to start animation:

```
animImgView.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
final AnimationDrawable frameAnim = (AnimationDrawable) animImgView.getBackground();
frameAnim.setVisible(true, true);
```

and setVisible(false, **true**) to stop it (note the bold **true**):

```
final AnimationDrawable frameAnim = (AnimationDrawable) animImgView.getBackground();
frameAnim.setVisible(false, true);
animImgView.setVisibility(View.GONE);
```